# 1,2V on input pin of a 74LS273

Tags: voltage

We're building [Ben Eater's CPU](https://eater.net/8bit). We have voltage on the bus of ~1.4V.

We isolated a 74LS273 and wired it like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqv5Ei.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At VM, we're measuring 1.2 V even with a 10k pulldown resistor.

Why is that and how do I get it closer to 0V? I need the voltage below ~0.3V so that other components as the 74LS157 will properly detect it as a digital LOW.

Of course I can replace the pulldown resistor by 0 Ohm (we tried and it worked), but then the input becomes completely unusable.

This is in a less professional environment. We have ESD protection, but I cannot completely ensure it has always been used. Is it an indicator that the 74LS273 is broken?

Comment: The "rule-of-thumb" for low-power-Schottky input when you pull down to logic low is around **0.4mA**. The upper limit of a logic low is 0.8V. To get to that *very edge* you need a 2K pull-down. You'll need an even *smaller* resistor for noise immunity. **You decide** how much noise immunity you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bens CPU the input of the 74LS273 is connected directly to the BUS. The BUS is pulled down to ground using a 10K Resistor. As you can measure the 10k resistor is not enough to pull it to ground.

There are several other components connected to the BUS. One of the components is a Tri-State-Buffer, the 74LS245. When the output of the 74LS245 is activated, a signal is put onto the BUS. If the output of the 74LS245 is LOW, it will pull the input of the 74LS273 to ground and the 74LS273 will detect it as LOW.

There is a voltage at the input of the 74LS273 because no other component is connected to it which acts output (eg. no 74LS245 has its outputs enabled).

Try to put the signal on the BUS using a 74LS245, then the issue is gone.

Comment: Thanks. That's it. We indeed had a command in our microcode which did not set an output.

Answer (score 3):

The 74LS273 is a "Low Power Schottky" logic chip so its inputs aren't high impedance as is the case with CMOS logic.

If we look at [TI's datasheet 74LS273](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls273-sp.pdf) (the one from [Motorola](http://www.skot9000.com/ttl/datasheets/273.pdf) doesn't show this) we see input circuits:

[image]

Where you're using the Data input so it must have \$R_{eq}\$ = 8 kohm.

By itself this circuit would result in a higher voltage at the input when INPUT is connected to ground via 10 kohm so maybe your 74LS273 has a different value \$R_{eq}\$.

Anyway, the "obvious" solution is to pull down the input even "harder" using a lower value resistor, for example 1 kohm instead of 10 kohm. I'm not that familiar with LS logic (I'm more of a CMOS man) but I guess that these inputs are designed to work with **open collector** outputs which "pull down" quite strongly. You could consider adding a **buffer** to properly pull down this voltage.

Regarding ESD, I personally would not be too worried, I have never knowingly destroyed a chip through ESD either as a professional or a hobbyist. Also these 74LS chips aren't that sensitive and also have proper ESD protection. The easiest way to check is to try a different IC of the same type or a different input on the same IC, if that (input or chip) behaves the same, your chip(s) should be OK.